# Get unique values using STRING_AGG in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2017, string-aggregation

The following query returns the results shown below:

```
SELECT 
    ProjectID, newID.value
FROM 
    [dbo].[Data] WITH(NOLOCK)  
CROSS APPLY 
    STRING_SPLIT([bID],';') AS newID  
WHERE 
    newID.value IN ('O95833', 'Q96NY7-2')
```

Results:

```
ProjectID   value
---------------------
2           Q96NY7-2
2           O95833
2           O95833
2           Q96NY7-2
2           O95833
2           Q96NY7-2
4           Q96NY7-2
4           Q96NY7-2
```

Using the newly added `STRING_AGG` function (in SQL Server 2017) as it is shown in the following query I am able to get the result-set below.

```
SELECT 
    ProjectID,
    STRING_AGG( newID.value, ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY newID.value) AS 
NewField
FROM
    [dbo].[Data] WITH(NOLOCK)  
CROSS APPLY 
    STRING_SPLIT([bID],';') AS newID  
WHERE 
    newID.value IN ('O95833', 'Q96NY7-2')  
GROUP BY 
    ProjectID
ORDER BY 
    ProjectID
```

Results:

```
ProjectID   NewField
-------------------------------------------------------------
2           O95833,O95833,O95833,Q96NY7-2,Q96NY7-2,Q96NY7-2
4           Q96NY7-2,Q96NY7-2
```

I would like my final output to have only unique elements as below:

```
ProjectID   NewField
-------------------------------
2           O95833, Q96NY7-2
4           Q96NY7-2
```

Any suggestions about how to get this result? Please feel free to refine/redesign from scratch my query if needed.

Comment: So you have data stored as delimited values and now you want to split them, find distinct values and finally cram them all back into a delimited string? YUCK!!! Delimited data violates 1NF. That is why you are struggling so much here. You will have to use STUFF and FOR XML with DISTINCT thrown in to do this after you first split it.

Comment: SQL Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/0b959/1

Comment: Any simple example on how to use the STUFF and FOR XML with DISTINCT in my dataset? I can't avoid STRING_SPLIT as unfortunately the raw data is stored as delimited values as you realised.

Comment: And be careful with that NOLOCK hint. https://blogs.sentryone.com/aaronbertrand/bad-habits-nolock-everywhere/

Answer (score 63, accepted):

Use the `DISTINCT` keyword in a subquery to remove duplicates before combining the results: [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/0b959/6)

```
SELECT 
 ProjectID
,STRING_AGG(value, ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY value) AS 
NewField
FROM (
    SELECT DISTINCT 
      ProjectID
    , newId.value 
    FROM [dbo].[Data] WITH (NOLOCK)  
    CROSS APPLY STRING_SPLIT([bID],';') AS newId  
    WHERE newId.value IN (   'O95833' , 'Q96NY7-2'  )  
) x
GROUP BY ProjectID
ORDER BY ProjectID
```

Comment: ps. a couple of comments on the documentation have asked for `distinct` keyword support for this function; so maybe MS will consider adding such functionality in a future version: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-agg-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: Please give you vote here for DISTINCT: https://feedback.azure.com/forums/908035-sql-server/suggestions/35243533-support-distinct-for-string-agg

Comment: Updated link to vote for DISTINCT:  https://feedback.azure.com/d365community/idea/0e8fa860-7c25-ec11-b6e6-000d3a4f0da0

Answer (score 14):

This is a function that I wrote that answers the OP Title:
Improvements welcome!

```
CREATE OR ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[fn_DistinctWords]
(
  @String NVARCHAR(MAX)  
)
RETURNS NVARCHAR(MAX)
WITH SCHEMABINDING
AS
BEGIN
  DECLARE @Result NVARCHAR(MAX);
  WITH MY_CTE AS ( SELECT Distinct(value) FROM STRING_SPLIT(@String, ' ')  )
  SELECT @Result = STRING_AGG(value, ' ') FROM MY_CTE
  RETURN @Result
END
GO
```

Use like:

```
SELECT dbo.fn_DistinctWords('One Two      Three Two One');
```

Answer (score 7):

You can use `distinct` in the subquery used for the `apply`:

```
SELECT d.ProjectID,
       STRING_AGG(  newID.value, ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY newID.value) AS 
NewField
FROM [dbo].[Data] d CROSS APPLY
     (select distinct value
      from STRING_SPLIT(d.[bID], ';') AS newID 
     ) newID
WHERE newID.value IN (   'O95833' , 'Q96NY7-2'  ) 
group by projectid;
```

Comment: This is especially useful if you have more than one other column besides the one that needs to be split and aggregated.

Answer (score 6):

Here is my improvement on @ttugates to make it more generic:

```
CREATE OR ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[fn_DistinctList]
(
  @String NVARCHAR(MAX),
  @Delimiter char(1)
)
RETURNS NVARCHAR(MAX)
WITH SCHEMABINDING
AS
BEGIN
  DECLARE @Result NVARCHAR(MAX);
  WITH MY_CTE AS ( SELECT Distinct(value) FROM STRING_SPLIT(@String, 
@Delimiter)  )
  SELECT @Result = STRING_AGG(value, @Delimiter) FROM MY_CTE
  RETURN @Result
END
```

Answer (score 3):

As @SeanLange pointed out in the comments, this is a terrible way to pull out the data, but if you **had** to, just make it 2 separate queries as follows:

```
SELECT 
    ProjectID
    ,STRING_AGG( val, ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY val) AS NewField
FROM
(
    SELECT DISTINCT 
        ProjectID
        ,newID.value AS val
    FROM 
        [dbo].[Data] WITH(NOLOCK)  
        CROSS APPLY STRING_SPLIT([bID],';') AS newID  
    WHERE 
        newID.value IN ('O95833' , 'Q96NY7-2') 
) t
GROUP BY
    ProjectID
```

That should do it.

Answer (score 2):

Another possibility to get unique strings from `STRING_AGG` would be to perform these three steps after fetching the comma separated string:

1. Split the string (`STRING_SPLIT`)
2. Select `DISTINCT` from the splits
3. Apply `STRING_AGG` again to a select with a group on a single key

Example:

```
(select STRING_AGG(CAST(value as VARCHAR(MAX)), ',') 
        from (SELECT distinct 1 single_key, value 
            FROM STRING_SPLIT(STRING_AGG(CAST(customer_division as VARCHAR(MAX)), ','), ',')) 
                q group by single_key) as customer_division
```

Answer (score 1):

For your particular case instead of exploding the values from the rows out and intermingling them and then needing to use `GROUP BY` to reassemble them you can just do the following ([Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/z2O7kwji)).

```
SELECT ProjectId, 
      NewField = (SELECT  STRING_AGG( value, ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY value) FROM  (SELECT DISTINCT value FROM STRING_SPLIT(bID,';') WHERE value IN ('O95833', 'Q96NY7-2') )X)
FROM [data]
```

In the more general case - e.g. with the starting point in [Darryl's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77671926/73226) you could use

```
 WITH T AS
 (
SELECT *,  
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ProjectID, value ORDER BY ProjectID, value) AS RN
FROM #data d
)
SELECT ProjectID,
       SUM(Cost),
       STRING_AGG(CASE WHEN RN = 1 THEN value END, ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY value)
FROM T
GROUP BY ProjectID
ORDER BY ProjectID
```

This can use a single sort on `ProjectID, value` to both apply the row numbering and for the subsequent `GROUP BY ProjectID` and `WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY value)`

[Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/3kSL-7wK)

Answer (score 1):

You can use that function to remove duplicates:

```
CREATE FUNCTION fn_DistinctSeparatedList (@InputString VARCHAR(MAX), @separator nvarchar(10))
RETURNS VARCHAR(MAX)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @Items TABLE (Item VARCHAR(MAX));

    INSERT INTO @Items
    SELECT value 
    FROM STRING_SPLIT(replace(@InputString, @separator,'~'),'~')
    WHERE value IS NOT NULL AND value != '';

    WITH DistinctItems AS (
        SELECT DISTINCT Item AS Item
        FROM @Items
    )

    SELECT @InputString = STRING_AGG(Item, '~') 
    FROM DistinctItems;
    
    RETURN Replace(@InputString,'~',@separator);
END
```

you can use that this way:
let's create the table to have some data:

```
drop table if exists #PetsOwner
Select 'Olivier' as Person, 'Cat' as Pet, 'Charlie' as PetName
into #PetsOwner
union
Select 'Olivier' as Person, 'cat' as Pet, 'Luna' as PetName
union
Select 'Olivier' as Person, 'Cat' as Pet, 'Cooper '  as PetName
union 
Select 'Leo' as Person, 'Cat' as Pet, 'Daisy'  as PetName
union 
Select 'Leo' as Person, 'Dog' as Pet, 'Milo'  as PetName
union
Select 'Michael' as Person, 'Fish' as Pet, 'Max'  as PetName
```

And now we can aggregate with duplicates:

```
select Person, STRING_AGG(Pet, ', ')
from #PetsOwner
group by Person
```

Or without duplicates with the usage of that function:

```
select Person, fn_DistinctSeparatedList(STRING_AGG(Pet, ', '),', ')
from #PetsOwner
group by Person
```

Comment: Not sure how this would affect performance for large datasets, but it is certainly the simplest solution for my needs. Makes the SQL much easier to read and the function can be reused.

Comment: @JoG I'm almost certain that this is not the best approach in terms of performance. As you mentioned, I chose this method because it's simple to use. However, for large datasets, it would be better to use a different method.

Answer (score 0):

You can make a distinct view of the table, that holds the aggregate values, that is even simpler:

```
Create Table Test (field1 varchar(1), field2 varchar(1));

go

Create View DistinctTest as (Select distinct field1, field2 from test group by field1,field2);

go

insert into Test Select 'A', '1';
insert into Test Select 'A', '2';
insert into Test Select 'A', '2';
insert into Test Select 'A', '2';
insert into Test Select 'D', '1';
insert into Test Select 'D', '1';

select string_agg(field1, ',')  from Test where field2 = '1';  /* duplicates: A,D,D */;

select string_agg(field1, ',')  from DistinctTest where field2 = '1';  /* no duplicates: A,D  */;
```

Answer (score -1):

In case you want to include other aggregates with your query, you can do:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #data
CREATE TABLE #data (row_id INT IDENTITY(1,1), projectID INT, value NVARCHAR(40), cost FLOAT)
INSERT INTO #data(projectID, value, cost )
VALUES 
 (2,'Q96NY7-2',100) 
,(2,'O95833'  ,100) 
,(2,'O95833'  ,100) 
,(2,'Q96NY7-2',100) 
,(2,'O95833'  ,100) 
,(2,'Q96NY7-2',100) 
,(4,'Q96NY7-2',100) 
,(4,'Q96NY7-2',100) 
 
SELECT projectID  = d.projectID
     , value      = REPLACE(STRING_AGG(IIF(x.row_id = d.row_id, x.value, '(x)'),',')   WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY IIF(x.row_id = d.row_id, x.value, '(x)')), '(x),','')
     , Cost       = SUM(d.COST)
FROM #data d
JOIN (  SELECT DISTINCT projectid, value, row_id = MIN(row_id) 
        FROM #data 
        GROUP BY projectid, value 
     ) x ON x.projectid = d.projectid AND x.value = d.value
GROUP BY d.projectID
```

| projectID | value | Cost |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | O95833,Q96NY7-2 | 600 |
| 4 | Q96NY7-2 | 200 |

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**

Answer (score -7):

Oracle (since version 19c) [suports](https://livesql.oracle.com/apex/livesql/file/content_HT1O85E4BHSBWN93G1B3M8SI2.html) `listagg (DISTINCT ...`, but Microsoft SQL Server not probably.

Comment: OP was not asking about Oracle