# How to avoid duplicates in the STRING_AGG function SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I was testing a query in SQL in which I need to concatenate values ​​in the form of a comma-separated list, and it works, I just have the problem of duplicate values.

This is the query:

```sql
SELECT t0.id_marcas                                AS CodMarca, 
       t0.nombremarcas                             AS NombreMarca, 
       t0.imagenmarcas, 
       (SELECT String_agg((t2.name), ', ')
        FROM exlcartu_devcit.store_to_cuisine t1 
               INNER JOIN exlcartu_devcit.cuisine t2 
                       ON t1.cuisine_id = t2.cuisine_id 
        WHERE  store_id = (SELECT TOP 1 store_id 
                           FROM   exlcartu_devcit.store 
                           WHERE  id_marcas = t0.id_marcas 
                                  AND status = 1)) AS Descripcion, 
       t0.logo, 
       t0.imagen, 
       (SELECT TOP 1 preparing_time 
        FROM   exlcartu_devcit.store 
        WHERE  id_marcas = t0.id_marcas 
               AND status = 1)                     AS Tiempo, 
       t0.orden, 
       (SELECT TOP 1 Avg(minimum_amount) 
        FROM   exlcartu_devcit.store_delivery_zone 
        WHERE  id_marcas = t0.id_marcas)           AS MontoMinimo 

FROM   exlcartu_devcit.[marcas] t0
```

I thought the solution could be just adding a `DISTINCT` to the query to avoid repeated values ​​in this way ...

```sql
(SELECT STRING_AGG(DISTINCT (t2.name),  ', ') AS Descripcion
```

But apparently the `STRING_AGG()` function does not support it, any idea how to avoid repeated values?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get unique values using STRING\_AGG in SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50589064/get-unique-values-using-string-agg-in-sql-server)

Answer (score 0):

Simplest way is just `select from select`, like this:

```
with dups as (select 1 as one union all select 1 as one)
select string_agg(one, ', ') from (select distinct one from dups) q;
```

vs original

```
with dups as (select 1 as one union all select 1 as one)
select string_agg(one, ', ') from dups;
```