# Aggregate values in columns ONLY there is a difference

Tags: sql, aggregation, sql-server-2017

Where the values of one column match I want to:

1. aggregate the data in the other columns where there is a different between the two values
2. If the values are the same the take the value

Example data

```
Name  Surname Age
Ryan  Smith   28
Ryan  Smith   29
Sean  Johnson 37
```

Desired result:

```
Name  Surname Age
Ryan  Smith   28, 29
Sean  Johnson 37
```

Name `ryan` appears twice, so want to aggregate the data for the other fields surname and age ONLY where the data is different for the two rows.

Surname is Smith in both rows so no need to aggregate, just want to populate as Smith in one row.

Age is different so want to aggregate the ages for the two rows into one row

`Sean Johnson` record is unique for all columns so no need to aggregate or amend anything

I have tried `string_agg` function but this gives the result:

```
Name  Surname          Age
Ryan  Smith, Smith     28,29
Sean  Johnson           37
```

It aggregates all fields irrespective of whether the data between the two rows is different or not.

Comment: Please show the queries that you tried.

Comment: Don't use `string_agg()` on `surname` and you will be all set. `SELECT Name, Surname, String_Agg(age) FROM yourtable GROUP BY Name, Surname;` If you are getting multiples of the same value inside the `string_agg()` output then you can subquery with a `SELECT DISTINCT` first [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50589064/get-unique-values-using-string-agg-in-sql-server)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get unique values using STRING\_AGG in SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50589064/get-unique-values-using-string-agg-in-sql-server)

Comment: The only thing is surname may some times have different values, sometimes it will not. When the surname is different the different surnames need to be aggregate, when the surnames are the same the no aggregation is needed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use:

```
select name, string_agg(distinct surname, ',') as surname, string_agg(age, ',')
from t
group by name;
```

This assumes that all `name`s are unique -- that seems like a strong assumption for most datasets.