# Aggregate and count disctinct values with a join

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, group-by, distinct

This question is a mix of those duplicates:

- [Get unique values using STRING_AGG in SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50589064/get-unique-values-using-string-agg-in-sql-server)
- [SQL/mysql - Select distinct/UNIQUE but return all columns?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6127338/sql-mysql-select-distinct-unique-but-return-all-columns)

I just can't manage to make it work all at once.

I have two tables :

```
TABLE A
IntervalId    Starts  Ends
-------------------------
1              0      10
2             10      25
3             25      32
4             32      40

TABLE B
Id            ErrorType    Starts    Ends
----------------------------------------
1                   666       0      25
2                   666       10     32
3                   777       0      32
4                   666       25     40
5                   777       10     25
```

Starting from the time intervals in table B, I'm trying to **count and list**, in each interval, the error types that might have happened during that interval. And **remove duplicates**.

Please note that there isn't any Start or End in table B that does not exist in Table A (Table A is generated from them).

the result *with duplicates* would be this :

```
Starts      Ends        ErrorsCount      Errors
-----------------------------------------------
0           10          2                 666, 777
10          25          4                 666, 666, 777, 777
25          32          3                 666, 777, 666
32          40          1                 666
```

The result I'm looking for is **without duplicates**:

```
Starts      Ends        DistinctErrorsCnt  DistinctErrors
-----------------------------------------------
0           10          2                 666, 777
10          25          2                 666, 777
25          32          2                 666, 777
32          40          1                 666
```

Here is my attemot, but I can't understand how to get ErrorType out of the bit that does the "distinct" without SQL server complaining that it's not in an aggregate or group by. Or, as soon as I put it into a Group by, then all the different Error Types are wiped by the first one that comes around. I end up with only 666 everywhere.

```
SELECT 
    IntervalId,
    Starts,
    Ends,
    COUNT([TableB].ErrorType) as DistinctErrorsCnt,
    DistinctErrors= STRING_AGG([TableB].ErrorType, ',')
FROM
(
    SELECT DISTINCT  
        [TableA].IntervalId,

    FROM TableB LEFT JOIN TableA ON
        (
            [TableA].Starts= [TableB].Starts
        OR [TableA].Ends = [TableB].Ends
        OR ([TableA].Starts >= [TableB].Starts AND [TableA].Ends <= [TableB].Ends)

        )
    GROUP BY 
        [TableA].IntervalId,
        [TableA].Starts, 
        [TableA].Ends, 
) NoDuplicates
GROUP BY 
    NoDuplicates.IntervalId,
    NoDuplicates.Starts, 
    NoDuplicates.Starts
```

Again: This is not syntactically correct, for the reason I explained above.

Comment: STRING_AGG(DISTINCT...) does not exist in SQL server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use aggregation:

```
select 
    a.starts,
    a.ends,
    count(distinct b.errorType) DistinctErrorsCnt,
    string_agg(b.errorType, ', ') within group(order by b.starts) DistinctErrors
from tablea a
inner join tableb b on b.starts >= a.ends and b.ends <= a.start
group by a.intervalId, a.start, a.end
```

If you want to avoid duplicates, you could use a subquery, or better yet, `cross apply`:

```
select
    a.starts,
    a.ends,
    count(*) DistinctErrorsCnt,
    string_agg(b.errorType, ', ') within group(order by b.starts) DistinctErrors
from tablea a
cross apply (
    select distinct errorType from tableb b where b.starts >= a.ends and b.ends <= a.start
) b
group by a.intervalId, a.start, a.end
```

Comment: Despite the alias b being used twice and b.starts requiring to be replaced with a.starts on the line with the string_agg, this works. Thanks!