# SQL Server change FOR XML PATH to STRING_AGG

Tags: sql, sql-server

How to convert FOR XML PATH to string_agg?

```
Stuff((SELECT '' + @delimiter + '' + [Column]  
       FROM CTE GROUP BY [column]
      FOR XML PATH('') ),1,1,'')
```

I was trying like

```
STRING_AGG('', @delimiter, '', [Column] )   FROM CTE  GROUP BY [Column]
```

But not getting the expected result. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please provide some sample data and the expected result as tables in your question, see https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example At first glance, it seems incorrect to me to group by the same column which is used in STRING_AGG, but your question is too vague to be sure about the correct query.

Comment: FYI, `STUFF` isn't doing the work here, it's `FOR XML PATH`. All `STUFF` is doing it removing the first character from a string.

Comment: While asking a question, you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements. 
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in T-SQL. 
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in the #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;).

Answer (score 2):

You are trying this:

```
STRING_AGG('', @delimiter, '', [Column] )   FROM CTE  GROUP BY [Column]
```

which means you want to concatenate the values in the `column`, but grouping by the same values. So, you will get only one value.

From here, first remove the `GROUP BY` and use the correct [syntax](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-agg-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16):

```
STRING_AGG([Column],@delimiter) FROM CTE
```

Also, pay attention to this section from the above linked documentation:

> ### Return Types
>
> Return type depends on first argument (expression). If input argument is string type (`NVARCHAR`, `VARCHAR`), result type will be same as input type. The following table lists automatic conversions:
>
> | Input expression type | Result |
> | --- | --- |
> | NVARCHAR(MAX) | NVARCHAR(MAX) |
> | VARCHAR(MAX) | VARCHAR(MAX) |
> | NVARCHAR(1...4000) | NVARCHAR(4000) |
> | VARCHAR(1...8000) | VARCHAR(8000) |
> | int, bigint, smallint, tinyint, numeric, float, real, bit, decimal, smallmoney, money, datetime, datetime2, | NVARCHAR(4000) |

If you are expecting the concatenated string to exceed VARCHAR(8000) or NVARCHAR(4000), you need to cast the value like this:

```
STRING_AGG(CAST([Column] AS VARCHAR(MAX)),@delimiter) FROM CTE
```

Comment: If you expect the value to *exceed* 8,000/4,000 characters, you need to `CAST`/`CONVERT` to a `MAX`. `CAST`ing to a `varchar(8000)` will result in a truncation error if the value results in more than than many characters, as (as the documentation you quote states) providing a non-`MAX` value results in a non-`MAX` length value being returned.

Comment: @Larnu Thank you for improving the quality, also for noting the error.

Comment: @gotqn, thanks for guiding. Yes, my string concatenation is works. But i want to remove the duplicate string. Eg (abc, def, abc), the output should be like (abc, def)

Comment: @moor in order to remove the duplicates, you need first to perform DISTINCT.  Check this answer - https://stackoverflow.com/q/50589064/1080354